# Socket.io-client would loop and never respond to an event

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I have a socket.io chat app for which I am trying to make a react frontend. However, `socket.io-client` would connect to my server endlessly without making any calls such as `socket.emit()` or respond to events with `socket.on()`. Here is my backend:

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.use(require('cors')());

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('new user connected');
    io.to(socket.id).emit('msg', 'hello there');

    socket.on('joining msg', ({id, username}) => {
        console.log(username);
        socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', `Everybody welcome ${username}\n`);
    })
});

server.listen(4001, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on :4001');
});
```

Whereas my frontend is:

```js
import React from "react";
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const socket = io("http://localhost:4001");
        socket.emit('joining msg', {id: 'test', username: 'test'})
        socket.on('msg', (msg) => {
            this.setState('data', msg);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <p>{this.state.data}</p>
        );
    }
}
```

The server console would endlessly log `new user connected` but never actually logs the username of the client which it emits. How do I prevent the loop and get my app to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to update `socket.io` version on my server, that's it!